# Drop the index position of a second array based on the first

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to program this in python. Suppose I have the arrays:

A = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

B = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'D', 'C']

I want to drop the corresponding element in array B, based on the index position of the dropped element in A. For example, if I drop 0 in A:

A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]

then B should drop the first 'A' and become:

B = ['A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'D', 'C']

Any idea how to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Side note: those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: You can drop an element at a given index using `del B[index]`.

Comment: How are you "dropping" the element in `A`? Using the index?

Comment: I am dropping the element in A based off the index of any 0 that may be located in the list A. For example, if 0 is located at index 3 in list A, then I need to drop whatever element is located in index 3 of list B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what dropping the element from A does, but I believe this is what you're trying to do.

```
A = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
B = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'E', 'D', 'D', 'C']

todrop = 0
i = A.index(todrop)
del A[i]
del B[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

In python, there are some arrays such as in numpy but these elements you pointed are lists, you can delete these elements using the del operator and if you want to do that in an automated manner you can build a function to compute it properly, such as:

```
def removeFromBothLists(a, b, idx):
    del a[idx]
    del b[idx]
```

And then you can call it passing the lists as arguments and the index you want to delete:

```
removeFromBothLists(a, b, 0)
```